# Retrieve Console Output dynamically into GUI window in Win32 API

Tags: winapi

Consider the case of a separate executable which has to be called from another application, and the console application emits its progress through `stdout`, `stderr` outputs. Now, I referred [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2537/Running-console-applications-silently) article on Codeproject, and it allows me to run this application silently. However my main application appears completely frozen as it should since the console application takes its time to finish. Now, it'd be nice to be able to capture the console output and show the progress messages on a 'GUI-like' read-only window as here:
[image]
I know it can be done, as they have done for large programs like `ffmpeg`, etc that are console based. How can it be done in Win32 API?

Comment: You need to run the GUI and the console in separate threads.

Comment: So the executable is a DOS (console) application. Then just spawn a DOS box and see the output in the DOS box?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie No, it's not DOS. It's a Win32 console mode process.

Comment: It's not a DOS program. Besides, since it is called from inside of an interactive application I need to show some progress and life signs.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, console applications are regular Windows PE executables with the subsystem set to the Windows console. This causes the kernel32 (or kernelbase) startup code to allocate a console automatically. A GUI Windows program has to get a console manually if it needs one, via `AllocConsole` or `AttachConsole`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way is to create a thread that reads the stdout and stderr of the child process. When there is new content, this thread notifies the UI thread which then displays it.

Comment: I suppose, this must be implemented via some callback. I'll try to look more into API documentation. From what I have understood from your answer is when there is more output, this could trigger an event, which could then trace to a callback function, and then this function should push its output stream into the window which should then handle it to display it, scroll it, or maybe even write to file.

Comment: No, you just use a blocking read. But you don't mind blocking in the thread. That doesn't impact the UI.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to read more. I'll get back if I'm stuck. Thanks!

Comment: I see from [this][1] example here, that `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()` returns handle to the console, and `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()` can then be used to read console output. I'll have to program the synchronization.


  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esszf9hw.aspx

Comment: I would do that. I'd use pipes.